# Delete all .htaccess files form host using php script

Tags: php, .htaccess, host

i need to delete all .htaccess files from the host but unfortunately a terminal is not available so may be it can be done using a php script.
example: host path is home/name/public_html/ and inside the public_html folder there are other folders and subfolders and using a php script i was able to output all files path and count all .htaccess files (around 9000)...
Please anyone can help to delete all these files as going folder by folder(subfolder) will take weeks as there are more than 8k folders/subfolders.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) to get the locations of all the .htaccess files, then loop over and [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink)

Comment: thanks @LawrenceCherone in fact i used that function to show up all the paths for all files but i'm stuck on how to get only the .htaccess file and then i know i can use unlink to delete it.. an example would be very appreciated.

Comment: Well you already know the filename so just concatenate that with the current directory name identified by the iterator

Comment: But tbh if a php script (triggered, i assume, by a web request) has sufficient permissions to delete the htaccess files (or any other files) from its own website folders then your site has a pretty serious security issue. Generally the webserver/php should only have read permission to such folders, and only be able to modify certain folders/files actually necessary for the application running on the server (e.g. an uploads folder or something like that).

Comment: @ADyson Mmmmm, I wonder how the 9K `.htaccess` files got there in the first place!?

Comment: the entire host got infected with a minishell and it creates .htaccess files on each folder/subfolder everywhere :( and the host doesn't allow a ssh access

Comment: OK well clear those files and then change the permissions to stop it happening again

Answer (score 5):

thanks to @LawrenceCherone for the indication on [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Got an example there and with few changes i was able to figure it out
Here is the script in case anyone will need it on future:

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(getcwd());
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);

foreach($files as $file){
    $name_of_file = $file->getFileName();
    $path_of_file = $file->getPath()."/".$file->getFileName(); 
    //need to concatenate "/" otherwise it shows all attached (path and file name)
    if ($name_of_file == ".htaccess") {
        //echo $path_of_file . "<br />";
        unlink($path_of_file);
    }
}
```

Thanks to all for the help.